Problems with package of android ads for unity 6 6000.0.26f1 LTS
I'm creating a game using unity and C#, in this game I want to set some ads using Android. I have installed the packages as you can see in the image below:

In the image below is my unity tring to resolve a Android dependeces. But the resolving do not do anithing, it seems locked.

In one video on youtube(link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjqGhfT5QDk&t=86s) the guy fixed the problem, but as I said above my resolve is locked different of him.
ChatGPT states that It appears the error persists due to an issue related to Gradle and the path to the required files. And I Tried to do everything that ChatGPT suggests like install SDK, JDK and NDK e nothing fixed my problem.
My version of unity is 6 (6000.0.26f1) LTS.
I switched my plataform for android as the image below.

Maybe someone can help me to fixe this problem.

Try googling unity android resolve stuck at zero percent or unity levelplay android resolve failing, just to start with something. Maybe some of the advices in Unity Discussions will help. Unfortunately, this is how you develop for Android. It can break at any time in many various ways, and you have to find a solution that works for your particular issue.

Try to run the command in a console window, maybe you can see more details.
